# Black screen on second monitor, but only on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell XPS15 1970 laptop, with nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card.

I have a second monitor connected directly to the computer with an HDMI cable.

When I boot the computer with Ubuntu 20.04, the external monitor works great, no problems. When I boot with Windows 10, the display settings detect the external monitor (i.e., it shows 2 displays in the display window, I can move the cursor or windows onto the second monitor), but the actual monitor displays only a black screen (when I restart the monitor, it says "No signal" before showing the black screen).

The problem persists when I switch to different HDMI cables or to other external monitors. All the other questions I found on this same issue seem to boil down to "change the cable", but since Ubuntu handles the same monitor with the same cable, it doesn't feel like a hardware problem. Or if it is, what is Ubuntu doing that allows it to overcome the hardware problem?

I've had this problem for about 2 years. The windows partition used to handle external monitors without any problems.

Following a different trouble-shooting thread, I tried disabling the Intel graphics driver and restarting. After this, Windows could not detect the second monitor at all. After re-enabling the Intel driver, it detected the monitor again but still showed only a black screen.

Comment: Did you try updating the Video Driver.

Comment: Yes, I tried updating from the device manager, from nvidia's website, from intel's website, and from dell's website. The nvidia driver from dell did not install and gave an error, but it is also an earlier version than the driver that I have installed.

Comment: I would further try to install the Dell driver. Did uninstall current driver before attempting to install the Dell driver? Without restarting the computer inbetween, to prevent any driver from "auto-installing". (I had a graphic driver problem earlier, the culprit was a TeamViewer driver installing in the place of the original driver.)

Comment: While trying to do that, I've deleted the nvidia GPU from my system altogether. Whoops! But while I figure out how to re-install that, the monitor problem persists. However, the intel drivers updated just fine from Dell. So I have the most up-to-date intel drivers, but they're still not sending data to the monitor.