# No display on laptop but clear display on secondary monitor on a Dell Precision 7670

Tags: laptop, display

This is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1823883/) on Super User.

I have recently bought Dell Precision 7670 (2023), there is no display on main screen but proper display on external monitor. All other functions are as normal, full graphic capability on 3D softwares etc. In BIOS mode, I get the display on the main screen.

I have ran the advanced comprehensive diagnostic test in BIOS which took about 6 hours and no issues were identified.

The problem started 2 hrs after I connected an external screen for the first time. Before that it worked fine.

Dell has so far replaced the screen and motherboard but it is still the same.

If I disable the Intel driver, I get the display back on the main screen. But then I get a native laptop screen with max brightness and can't dim it at all. some other functions are limited too.

Even Dell engineers dont know what to do?

Comment: Have Dell replace the computer under warranty if they cannot fix it.

Comment: Have you set Settings > Display > Multiple Displays? Info in the question on what you've tried would help.

Comment: Its likely that the laptops monitor is simply set to disabled. It should automatically enable if you disconnect all external monitors.